# Swift 4 ¿Como centrar UIButtons dentro de un UIView dentro de un stackView?

Tags: swift, swift4

Estoy creando una aplicación con Swift 4.2 que debe presentar un formulario dinámico y, en cada pregunta, mostrar dos botones "Sí" y "No".

Mi problema es que soy incapaz de centrar los dos botones en el centro de la pantalla. Se me quedan en un lateral, y por más intentos que hago no puedo situarlos en el centro.

Como es un formulario dinámico lo tengo que hacer todo programáticamente.

Este es un resumen de mi código:

```
@IBOutlet weak var stackVertical: UIStackView!
        stackVertical.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackVertical.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackVertical.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackVertical.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackVertical.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackVertical.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackVertical.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackVertical.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stackVertical.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackVertical.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        stackVertical.spacing = 10
        stackVertical.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackVertical.axis = .vertical


    func createButtonSINO(){

    //1º Crear stackView horizontal
            let stackViewH = UIStackView()
            stackViewH.axis = .horizontal
            stackViewH.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            stackViewH.alignment = .center
            stackViewH.distribution = .equalSpacing
            stackViewH.spacing = 20

    //2º Crear 2 botones        
            let button3 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 60))
            button3.setTitle("Sí", for: .normal)        

            let button4 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 60))
            button4.setTitle("No", for: .normal)

    //3º Crear un UIView        
            let viw = UIView()//(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 10, height: 10))

    //4º Añadir los botones al stackView Horizontal        
            stackViewH.addArrangedSubview(button3)
            stackViewH.addArrangedSubview(button4)

    //5º Añadir el stackView horizontal al View        
            viw.addSubview(stackViewH)

    //6º Añadir el view a un stackView Vertical (creado en la interface) 
            self.stackVertical.addArrangedSubview(viw)

        }
```

Aunque pueda parecer un poco lioso, esto me funciona bien. Me crea un formulario con varias preguntas y bajo cada pregunta dos botones "Sí" y "No". Mi problema es que soy incapaz de centrar estos botones horizontalmente bajo cada pregunta. Se me quedan ambos en el lateral  izquierdo de la ventana.

He probado con la propiedad center, `button3.center = self.view.center` pero no me ha funcionado. Tampoco si lo que debo centrar son los botones o alguno de los views, stack views... Un poco lioso

Gracias.